# How to determine current row?

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am using Conditional Formatting to try and change the colour of a cell in column A if the text in Column B is certain values. Currently my three formula's are this:

```
=$B$2="Low"
=$B$2="Good"
=$B$2="High"
```

I need a way to quickly push this to all 50 columns therefore I thought if I could change the formula to the following it would work I just don't know how:

```
=$B$ThisCellsRow()="Low"
=$B$ThisCellsRow()="Good"
=$B$ThisCellsRow()="High"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using absolute cell references (the `$` in the address), which prevents Excel from adjusting the address as you add/remove rows and move the formula around. If you use `$B2` instead, as you drag down the formula, Excel can adjust it to be `$B3`, `$B4`, `$B5` and so on. With this format, the `B` column remains constant, and the row portion is flexible.

Comment: Very new to excel thank you very much! That's why I posted all my code ^_^!!!!! - 100% works